# how to change a form library item name on load without code behind?

Tags: infopath

I need to change he name  of the items added to a form library with a formula I got and I need to do it with infopath rules, is it possible? and how?

for example if I create a new item the name should be xx/2014, being xx for example the numbers of items in the form library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option I just tried.

Create a data connection to your form library. Create a field and set it's default value to a formula that is count(your data connection id field).

When I previewed the form, it showed me 57, the number of items in my list. You can then use this in another field or in a form rule to build a file name.